# Manga where four children are transported to another world and are given beast powers and accessories

Tags: story-identification, manga

There were four kids who were transported to another world and powers were given to them from these sacred beast guys. One was a white tiger that could control lightning, another was this panther with wings that could control wind and had a glove that could heal, a fire bird and this water lady that could see the future a bit.

When they first got their powers, all the kids got an accessory. The guy who gets the lightning tiger gets a necklace, the bird girl gets a phoenix. The water lady (who was taken and most likely brainwashed by the villain)  got an ankle bracelet and I can't remember what the wind guy got.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Note that as you were originally asking for 2 mangas this got closed as questions should be focused on one. However, another user edited out one of them to focus this on looking for one only. If you still want to find the other manga please ask it as a new question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like it might be [Vermonia](https://vermonia.com/manga.html); four youth are transported from Earth to the Turtle Realm to defend it against the army of General Uro.  They turn out to have been sent to Earth years before by Queen Frasinella before her world was destroyed, and each is bound to one of the Queen's ministers (in an animal form).

> **Jim** is a skate freak and bass player in Union City but in the Turtle Realm he has been chosen by Suiran, **the Winged Panther**, to possess the **power of wind** and trees. Jim's fallen hard for Rainbow, a Potonawi Princess, and will fight against anyone or anything that threatens her and her people.
>
> **Doug** is Jim's best friend and plays drums for their band Veracity. In the Turtle Realm he was the first to release his animal guardian Raitetsu, **the Silver Tiger**. Doug wears the sabertooth as a talisman and has Raitetsu's power to **throw thunder**.
>
> **Mel** is the daughter of Union City's mayor and the lead vocalist for Veracity. She's a prisoner in Turtle Realm and unable to release Ruka, her guardian. Mel is being forced to use her **powers of prophecy** to fight for General Uro.
>
> **Naomi** plays lead guitar for Veracity and is competing against Mel for the title of best skater in Union City. She leads the search for Mel in the Turtle Realm and draws upon the power of Suzaku, **the Red Phoenix**. Her animal guardian has given her the power of flight and fire.
>
> <sub>[Characters page on the official site](https://vermonia.com/characters.html)</sub>